# Is it possible to have multiple Typefaces in the same TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface

I know how to change text attributes and color for a `TextView`, but is it possible to have multiple `Typefaces` in the same `TextView`?
For instance, can I use both Droid Sans and Droid Mono in the same `TextView` at the same time?

If so, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually it looks like you can do it with the help of a Spannable:

```
String text = "This is an example";

Spannable s = new SpannableString(text + " text");
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("monospace"), 0, text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan("serif"), text.length(), s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view)).setText(s);
```