# Changing font of first letter in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts

Is there an easy way to change the font of the first letter in a string or word in Android? For example, I'd like to use an extravagant gothic font for the first letter of every word in a title, and then have the rest of the title in a smaller font.

Using custom imported fonts, so I'm not sure if HTML tags would work.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036685/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-typefaces-in-the-same-textview

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be to use a `Spannable` for the first letter with a different typeface, using a `TypefaceSpan`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7037054/1117415).

If you want to use your own custom font, you should [extend TypefaceSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826885/1117415).

Comment: Seems good so far, but any ideas how to detect the First Letter Of Every Word In A String?

Comment: @Muz your first letter is at `string.charAt(0);`

Comment: @Aman That detects the first letter of the string, but not the first letter in each word in the string.

Comment: @Muz , the the only way I can think of is use a tokenizer to separate each word change your `TypefaceSpan` and append it back, or do some type of parsing to detect `letter` after space.