# How to change the style of a font from a typeface without changing the other letters?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to implement a TypeFace in a TextView in java more with the following criteria:

This change will occur at the touch of a button.
When this button is pressed, the following letters entered will receive the changes without changing the previous ones.

When selecting a BOLD button at a certain time of the user's writing:

"This is an example (Button has been pressed now) **now the letters are bold** (Button has been pressed again) and now they have returned to their normal pattern."

I would like the logic of the Typeface to use the button.
my current solution does not meet the specified:
`descriptionField.setTypeface(Typeface.create ((String) null, Typeface.NORMAL));`
it ends up modifying all the letters that are in the TextView, but my intention was to make it change only the next words typed by the user

Comment: I assume you want to change only some letters or a series of words, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002305/changing-font-of-first-letter-in-android

Comment: I'll check it out, but my need would be to change the text style with bold for example anytime the user presses a button and with any word