# Custom Font to alphanumeric characters only Android.?

Tags: android, textview, typeface, custom-font

I need to apply font for alpha numeric characters only. All special characters must be drawn with degault font. Is this possible in Android if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [this](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) does match your needs

You can let all upper and lower case characters, as well as numbers have different styles, sizes, colors, ...

**[EDIT 1]**

You can:

```
mBox = new TextView(context);
mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
    "<small>" + description + "</small>" + "<br />" + 
    "<small>" + DateAdded + "</small>"));
```

where you can use the HTML tag **font-face**

**[EDIT 2]**

Here's an example of using two different fonts on the same Spannable

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036685/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-typefaces-in-the-same-textview)

Here it is shown how to load several different fonts from assets

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888508/how-to-change-the-font-on-the-textview)

By combining these two (and adding your code to compare each character to see if 
it falls in a case or the other) you should be able to get the results you're 
pursuing

I hope I helped.

Comment: Hi Klaus66,

This is not the one I am looking for.

I have a custom font which supports only alpha numeric characters, for special characters, it is showing some other symbols.

So here what i want is,
What ever text my textview has, it should be displayed in such a way that only apha numeric characters displayed in custom font and special characters must be displayed with default font.

But still thanks for your reply

Comment: So, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview). It has all you need.

Comment: Hey Klaus66
I guess you are not getting my requirements.
What ever you are saying is just applying different styles to part of strings and all.

I will be having n numbers of strings and i want to apply .ttf font to all the textViews used in the application.
But it should only apply font to Alphanumeric characters and not the special characters.

Comment: Well, so, you didn't read my second link!! There are AT LEAST two ways to do that...

Comment: Really? If so, what about: mBox.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font-face=Tahhoma>ABC</font-face><font-face=Verdana>+-+</font-face>"));

Comment: Agreed to your point sir...

But my font is custom font and i have a .ttf font present in assets folder.

How can i apply that font while saying <font-face > ?
Let me know if there is any way to read the font in Html.fromHtml from assets

Comment: I see... but maybe you can do the opposite: use your custom fon for the whole string... and then use <font-face=normal> (the default Roboto or Droid font) only on those characters which arent alphanumeric - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Comment: Maybe you'll find the [EDIT 2] section of my answer interesting.

Comment: Cheers! man!..

I didn't think of it...

You are great. I will surely do this.

Thanks once again

Comment: Tried doing this...
But it is taking the custom font which has been set using setTypeFace

There is no effect of Html.fromHtml("<font-face=Tahhoma>ABC</font-face><font-face=Verdana‌​>+-+</font-face>") 

on the text in the TextView

Comment: Boom!!!!! It worked.. man...

Just few syntax issue with html code...

<font face>text</font> and it worked 

Cheers!! Thanks once again..